# Why can't we use the let keyword inside a class in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am new to TypeScript. I want to know why we can't use the `let` keyword for variable declaration inside a class as below. Thanks in advance.

```
class Greeter {
    let greeting: string;
    constructor(message: string) {
        this.greeting = message;
    }
    greet() {
        return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
    }
}

let greeter = new Greeter("world");
console.log(greeter.greet())
```

Comment: What do you need let there for?

Comment: "greeting" isn't a variable, it is a property.  You only need to use "let" when you are instantiating a block variable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe your question is why *can't* we use let key word...

#### In TypeScript:

This is merely a syntactic choice I suppose, but class properties do not need a keyword. You can optionally add a `public` keyword or if you want the class property to be private for the type you can use the `private` keyword:

```
class Greeter {
  greeting: string;
  // or
  public greeting: string;
  //alternatively
  private greeting: string;
```

This is just to define the property for the purposes of the type. Later, when you do:

```
const greeter = new Greeter;
```

Now you will be able to use `greeter.greeting` and all string methods and TypeScript will transpile successfully. If `greeting` were not declared you would get an error when attempting to transpile

> `Property 'greeting' does not exist on type 'Greeter'`

#### In JavaScript:

There is currently no way to declare class properties in JavaScript at all. It's intentionally not supported.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is not a keyword in that context.  And given the purpose of `let`, I'm not sure it would ever make sense for it to be a keyword there -- it is used to restrict the scope of a variable.

Class properties (in languages that support them) are naturally restricted to the class, explicitly using the same syntax doesn't seem beneficial.

In particular, it works against how properties are currently added (assigned in the constructor), and causing confusing about what the scope actually is.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any specific documentation as to *why* but I believe the syntax for how `class` is transpiled simply requires that class-specific properties should not have any declaration. If you used `var`, same thing would happen and you can't use `const` in a `class`.

It's probably worth looking at the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) for future references. The final code that comes out seems to have it hoisted outside of the class?

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter() {
    }
    return Greeter;
}());
var greeting; // hmm?
constructor(message, string);
{
    this.greeting = message;
}
greet();
{
    return "Hello, " + this.greeting;
}
var greeter = new Greeter("world");
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.textContent = "Say Hello";
button.onclick = function () {
    alert(greeter.greet());
};
document.body.appendChild(button);
```

Interestingly in [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDiBOBTRAXR9oG8BQ0_RFWgHMlUBLAO2IC5oIV4riBuXfYAe0ofgFdgKTvAAUAW0RQwxRHV7MAlFnb58KABbkIAOlLIUzaAF5oEqTLaqAvipJkUIpTlWqkKPvErQARAAlEICCcADQ-0ADU0BpauvbMlvg2NtiEKHb66MbQlIgA7nD26CLeucIgACbeCmwpRABGfChCXiblnMB8EpQo2sBIYGgAooRdDgDkDU3cY9XYk83aaAAeKADC3GjdWd4AymAAntD-gZzebPPc2tyg5MAA1lkAZnyUguTcjsqqYITwDnqodCxfSOWbJNodUbaOqccr7bRgAAOiMQlHKq00FREF0o1SAA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0) you get an error when trying to do this. It's possible that Typescript might want to consider doing this too.